# Keeping cache in sync with backend

Tags: c#, caching, repository

Keep in mind, the example I'm showing here is only for explaining the problem as clearly as possible, not any real implementation or production code.

Also, let's assume that if anything gets stored or returned from backend, it will get cached. Example of how and where that happens, I omitted from the code.

For the scope of this problem, we also have to assume, the MyType collection is always small, fairly static and when the application starts, it will get everything from backend once and reuse the cached copies until the application is shut down. Which is why `GetCached(id)` and `GetBackend(id)` is actually just a wrapper for `ListCached` and `ListBackend`.

Suppose we have the following kind of simple repository:

```
public class MyRepository : IRepository<MyType>
{
    public IEnumerable<MyType> GetAll()
    {
        // Will return cached items if present
        return ListCached ?? ListBackend;
    }

    public MyType Get(int id)
    {
        return GetCached(id) ?? GetBackend(id);
    }


    private MyType GetBackend(int id)
    {
        return ListBackend.FirstOrDefault(type => type.Id == id);
    }

    private MyType GetCached(int id)
    {
        return ListCached.FirstOrDefault(type => type.Id == id);
    }

    protected IEnumerable<MyType> ListBackend
    {
        get { return Backend.GetAll<MyType>(); }
        set { Backend.StoreAll<MyType>(value); }
    }

    public IEnumerable<MyType> ListCached
    {
        get { return Cache.GetAll<MyType>(); }
        set { Cache.StoreAll<MyType>(value); }
    }

    public void Store(MyType value)
    {
        Backend.Store(value);
    }
}
```

And here's the challenge:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        #region Handling Missing Objects in Cache
        // We have a repository
        var rep = new MyRepository();

        // Into which we put stuff (3 for the demo)
        rep.Store(new MyType { Id = 1 });
        rep.Store(new MyType { Id = 2 });
        rep.Store(new MyType { Id = 3 });

        // And the repository, after this, returns 3 items
        // The items are returned from cache
        var count = rep.GetAll().Count(); // Returns 3

        // However, somewhere else in the application, it happens so,
        // for any reason, bug, programmer error, photon from sun hitting the cpu
        // or tinfoil-hat left home in rush,
        // that one item gets removed from the cache
        Cache.Remove(new MyType { Id = 2 });

        // After which, only 2 items are returned from the repository
        // since the cache exists, it won't even try to hit the database
        count = rep.GetAll().Count();

        // Now count = 2, while WE know the backend has now 3 items
        // how would the program detect it and get a fresh copy from backend?
        #endregion
    }
}
```

What would you do in this kind of situation? Is there patterns that would help to detect the situation and get fresh collection from backend. What would be the best practises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO ,

1- If you don't add in between into the database , then you can keep a counter and populate it when you start the application.

2- If you can change the List to Observable Collection which reports when its updated so when a item is removed , you will be notified and you can check with the counter if its not the same you can reload it.

3- if its not possible to use observable collection , then you can use concept of CacheExpiray policy , in which you can simulate a cache which will reload itself from source after some time period.

Answer (score 0):

There are maybe some options available.

First, use expiry cache. It is simply to set a specific expire for the current cache. If the time has passed then refresh the data. However, this pattern cannot

```
if(cacheExpiry){
  cacheList = GetListFromDatabase();
}
```

However if you want to ensure getting the latest data, usually I use this method:

1st, set the current timestamp when cache is generated. Some illustration:

```
DateTime lastCache = DateTime.Now
```

Then in your sql, have a table with latest modified date time (ex. UPDATE_STAMP). Then everytime you modify the desired cached table, update the record in UPDATE_STAMP table to current date. Example:

```
Update MyTable set //your code here
Update UPDATE_STAMP set DATE_TIME = GETDATE()
```

Then everytime you get the ListCached, compare the latest cached time with the UPDATE_STAMP table record. Example:

```
public IEnumerable<MyType> ListCached
{
    get { 
      DateTime latestModified = GetLatestModifiedDate();
      if(lastCache<latestModified) Cache = GetListFromDatabase();
      latestModified = DateTime.Now;
      return Cache.GetAll<MyType>();
    }
}
```

Comment: and everytime you need to get the cachedlist , you go to the databse to check it whether it is in sync , don't you think it is destroying the cache concept in a way.